# Entitymanager in symfony2 : replaced by webservice?

Tags: web-services, symfony, doctrine

I would like to know if it's possible to replace the entitymanager in symfony2 by a modified one that use a webservice to get and persist entity ?

Is there some bundle of this kind ?

Currently i use fosuserbundle & doctrine to manage my entities in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to solve the problem on the wrong level of abstraction.

Controllers and the like should be abstracted from the entity manager by a [layer of services](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). Then that layer could be configured to use the entity manager — or a Doctrine repository — or another data persisting mechanism.

Comment: Service, service everywhere :) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html